# Where to host web3.js and Infura websocket project?

Tags: web3js, nft, infura, hosting

I am working on a simple twitter bot to log sales of an NFT collection by subscribing to the `Transfer` event on the smart contract and posting a tweet after gathering info about the event. This works 100% fine when hosting locally on my local machine, but when I've tried to deploy it to Google App Engine, it runs fine for 30 min and then the app terminates with the following error:

> Start program failed: failed to detect app after start: ForAppStart(): [aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/valid" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:118818 aborted, context canceled. subject:"app/invalid" Timeout:30m0s, attempts:118837]

This has happened multiple times and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know where to host a project like this that it won't terminate after 30 min? I have included my code below.

```
async function getContractAbi() {
  const abi = await request(`${ETHERSCAN_ABI_URL}${CONTRACT_ADDRESS}`);
  return JSON.parse(JSON.parse(abi).result);
}

export async function subscribeToSales() {
  const abi = await getContractAbi();
  const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(WSS_PROVIDER));
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);

  contract.events
    .Transfer({})
    .on('connected', (subscriptionId: any) => {
      console.log(subscriptionId);
    })
    .on('data', (event: any) => {
      web3.eth.getTransaction(event.transactionHash).then((response) => {
        if (response.to === OPENSEA_ADDRESS) {
          const price = web3.utils.fromWei(response.value);
          const url = `${NFT_BASE_URL}${event.returnValues.tokenId}`;
          const nft: NftModel = {
            id: event.returnValues.tokenId,
            price: {
              price: +price,
              // TODO: find a way to get actual value and token type for non-eth txs
              token: 'eth',
              usdPrice: 0
            },
            fromAddress: event.returnValues.from,
            toAddresss: event.returnValues.to,
            url: url
          };
          postTweet(nft);
        }
      });
    })
    .on('changed', (event: any) => {
      // remove event from local database
      console.log('changed');
    })
    .on('error', (error: any, receipt: any) => {
      // If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the second parameter will be the receipt.
      console.log('error');
    });
}

subscribeToSales();
```

Comment: Did you get the infura websocket working on GAE? I have a similar problem, it works local but not on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this space but from what I understand you must set `session_affinity: true` in your app.yaml. And you should include a reconnect option in your WebsocketProvider.

[Persistent Connections with WebSockets on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-websockets-and-session-affinity)

```
network:
  session_affinity: true
```

[From a web3 release note](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/releases/tag/v1.2.7)

> The Websocket Provider module has been rewritten and now supports an auto-reconnect option which should dramatically improve the stability of connections to remote clients like Infura. You can enable auto-reconnect by configuring the provider as below.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const options = {
  // Enable auto reconnection
  reconnect: {
      auto: true,
      delay: 5000, // ms
      maxAttempts: 5,
      onTimeout: false
  }
};

const ws = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546', options)
```

Comment: I tried adding the `session_affinity: true` to the app.yaml and the application was still killed but I've noticed that it started to happen after 10 min rather than 30 like before. I did add the web3 reconnect option and that resolved the issue of crashing on disconnect locally but can't figure out how to prevent the cloud app from crashing.

Comment: fwiw I couldn't get it to work persistently with with Infura either. I moved over to Alchemy and I now have a successful persistent connection hosted on Google App Engine (it's been working non-stop for over a week now). I went down this path after I found this link, maybe it's useful to you too, good luck. https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/alchemy-web3